# Two angle line arrows CSS

Tags: css, border, pseudo-element, css-shapes

Is it possible to create two arrows like the photo below with css or I have to use a png or svg?

[image]

**So far**

**HTML**

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
a:after,
a:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 26px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  content: " ";
  height: 30px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 7px;
}
a:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: -11px;
}
a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Next</a>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laxmana/29jAs/1/)

I can't figure how to put another pair of borders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that was a good start, some fix : http://jsfiddle.net/29jAs/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit of tinkering of your example, it's possible, but you'd probably be better off using another method to draw it or using an icon or icon font.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/29jAs/2/)

Achieved with

```
transform: skew();
```

rather than rotate.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I would just use a SVG in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/6v7Np/

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
<div class="arrow_box alt"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    top:50px;
    left:60px;
}
.arrow_box.alt {
    left:80px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-width: 31px;
    margin-top: -31px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With gradients:

```
a{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

a::before{
  content: '';    
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;     
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0px, transparent 19px, black 20px, transparent 21px),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0px, transparent 19px, black 20px, transparent 21px),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0px, transparent 19px, black 20px, transparent 21px),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0px, transparent 19px, black 20px, transparent 21px);          
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-position: 0% top, 0% bottom, 50% top, 50% bottom;  
                              /* distance ^        ^ */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E8sRw/